# Can I re apply for UK visa after getting refused under V4.2 and V3.6?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

[image]

[image]

What do I do to get approval to my uk visit visa?

Comment: Do you have any favorable response to their statement your letter about employment was untrue?

Answer (score 5):

Okay so you were refused under V3.6 (a) and V4.2 of the [Appendix V of Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules), although the 4.2 is not important here, so let us bring up V3.6 for reference as this, is the onus of your refusal:

> V 3.6 An application will be refused where:
>
> (a) false representations
>   have been made or false documents or information have been submitted
>   (whether or not material to the application, and whether or not to the
>   applicant’s knowledge);

This is a very serious refusal as this means that they have got you on providing false information which is about the worst thing you a visa applicant can do. The letter also goes to explain that any future application may refused under V3.7 of the same appendix which would attract automatic 10 year ban.

So your next application will not only fight an uphill struggle as the refusal under 3.6 will be read by the ECO who will be handling it and because of it will receive extra scrutiny, but also if it's not successful you may attract the ban. Because of that you should find a practising solicitor who specialises in such cases, this is something that will be expensive, likely well into thousands of pounds, if you can even find a solicitor who would be willing to take your case.

What you really do not want to do is file another application without such representation, and do not try to hire some "immigration specialists" or other "travel agents" who do not have a registered practice in the UK as they will likely take your money away and do nothing good for your case.

Answer (score 3):

Engage an immigration solicitor, preferably from the UK, before you make any new application.

You are on a knife edge and only an expert in the field of U.K. immigration can prevent a 10 year ban now.

It won't be cheap.

Your only alternative is to forget visiting the UK for the foreseeable future.

Comment: If the letter was fake and the OP knew it (which seems to be the case here), he won't be going to the UK for the next 10 years.

Comment: @uberqe there is no ban *yet* but they will be looking for an excuse on the next application to enact one off the back of this.

Comment: @Moo, I don't think that is quite right. Under V3.7 they need no new excuse to ban the OP, the V3.6 refusal provides that (via V3.9). What they would need with the next application is evidence that the V3.6 refusal was unfounded, the ECO was mistaken in that finding and there is a perfectly reasonable explanation for the document (e.g. the person they talked to at the employer was mistaken). The only reason the OP isn't banned already is the possibility that such an explanation exists. If the document was in fact a fake then no such explanation will exist and the ban is a certainty.

Comment: @Dennis and that's the excuse they are looking for. This discussion has been had on here before - a ban is highly likely but not *guaranteed*, and there are other grounds where a ban won't be put in place (e.g. humanitarian) but that sort of application will only succeed with the backing of an immigration specialist, hence my answer.